# launch: program File name does not exist. launch.json:

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

This error appears every time you compile. The program itself is somehow compiled but not as it should, because it should open a separate console and not write everything in the built-in vscode

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations":[],
      
       "name": "GCCDebug",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "{fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "&{workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "dbg",
        "miDebugegrPath": "C:\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "preLaunchTask": "GCCDebug"
```

Comment: And how does your compile command look? Does it actually output an exe file with the expected path and name?

Comment: find the typo `"cwd": "&{workspaceFolder}"` and here `"program": "{fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"`

Comment: Does it mention the file name it tries to find? Does it match the file name you expect? Did compiling the file succeed without errors?

Comment: @Gerhardh the file name is mentioned but the name is not main.exe but main.exe

at compilation there is such error

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/503211497766256642/968588807446331392/unknown.png

Comment: OK, that means your compiler tells you it is not able to create the program you want but you ask why it cannot find the program that was not created? How would you expect it to find it? First you have to build a executable, then you can run/debug it. Look at the errors, search for existing question with same error. If you are not able to solve, then ask again how to fix those remaining errors.